# Replace character at specific position in textarea

Tags: javascript, string

is it posible to replace a character at a specific position within a textarea or textbox?  I can work out the position using indexOf() but knowing this how can i actually replace that particular character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function modText()
{
 var tb = document.getElementById("mtb");
 var indexToReplace = 1;
 var stringToPutIn= "!";
 var temp = tb.value;
 var startString = temp.substr(0, indexToReplace);
 var endString = temp.substring(indexToReplace+1);
 tb.value = startString+stringToPutIn+endString;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="mtb" /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="modText();">
</body>
</html>
```

The replace function will NOT work because you might have the same letter coming before the letter you wish to replace.

Note the above function only works if you're replacing one and only one character.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the built-in methods of JavaScript strings. Assuming you have a text area in a variable `textArea`:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("yourTextArea");
```

... the following creates a nice, generic, reusable string splicing function analogous to [`Array`'s `splice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Splice) that you can then use to update the textarea's value:

```
function spliceString(str, start, count, stringToInsert) {
  return str.slice(0, start) + stringToInsert + str.slice(start + count);
}

textArea.value = spliceString(textArea.value, charIndex, 1, "**NEW BIT**");
```

An alternative would be to create a splice method of all strings by augmenting `String`'s prototype:

```
String.prototype.splice = function(start, count, stringToInsert) {
  return this.slice(0, start) + stringToInsert + this.slice(start + count);
};

textArea.value = textArea.value.splice(charIndex, 1, "**NEW BIT**");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) or [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to do that (notice the different semantics of the second parameter):

```
var str = 'foobar';
alert(str.substr(3, 3));    // bar
alert(str.substring(3, 6)); // bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using `replace`

```
<input id="myTxtbox" type="textbox">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var txtbox = document.getElementByID("myTxtbox");
    document.write(txtbox.value.replace("To Replace", "With This"));
</script>
```

Comment: This will replace the first occurance of the string.  In most cases this will work, but the logic isn't correct.  
For example, lets say you have string of "apple cherry apple cherry"
if you called replace("apple", "orange"), you would only be able to replace the first apple [resulting in "orange cherry apple cherry"]  
  
Of course, you could use regexp's global... but that still wouldn't allow you to replace the nth instance of "apple"